# How do exclude elements from an Xpath query?

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to select the ingredients in an ingredients list, but there are also tooltips scattered amongst them (on the BBC Good Food site).

As a stripped-down example:

```
<li class="ingredients-list__item" itemprop="ingredients">
  400g
  <a href="/glossary/new-potatoes" class="ingredients-list__glossary-link tooltip-processed">
    new potato
    <div id="gf-tooltip-0" class="gf-tooltip" role="tooltip">
      <div class="gf-tooltip__content">
        <div class="gf-tooltip__text">
          <p>unwanted tooltip</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>, halved if large
  <span class="ingredients-list__glossary-element" id="ingredients-glossary"></span>
</li>
```

I'm trying to end up with `'400g new potato, halved if large'`, or equally good, `['400g', 'new potato', ', halved if large']`.

Amongst other things I've tried:

```
s.xpath("//li[@class='ingredients-list__item'][not(div[@class='gf-tooltip'])]//text()").extract()
```

But this still returns the text in the tooltip div.

Comment: Please say which version of XPath you are using. The solution is likely to be very different with different versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way would be excluding text nodes where any of the ancestor is a tooltip `div` (broken into 2 lines for readability) :

```
//li[@class='ingredients-list__item']
  //text()[not(ancestor::div[@class='gf-tooltip'])]
```

Comment: This is great. I didn't realise you could chain like that. But frustratingly while this works in the Chrome devtools xpath search, it doesn't in scrapy which still spits out the unwanted parts.